# Extract barcode from image

Tags: java, sdk, barcode-scanner, watson

Problem statement:
We have a table with multiple products, all pointing up with the 2d bar-code.
Taking a picture will result in one photo with multiple barcodes.

Question:
What java (Or other) SDK (or web service e.g. Watson?) would you use to get all the barcodes from the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an OCR engine for this purposes.
Try open source [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

Or you can use proprietary ABBY engine.